# how to add ejb 2.1 into java ee 6

Tags: reference, java-ee-6, ejb-2.x

Is there a way to use ejb 2.x project as a jar into Java EE 6 project?

I am using Rational Application Developer as IDE. I can add ejb 2.x project as a Java EE Utility jar. And **manually** add a reference to application.xml after than when i deployed to server the ejb jar automatically started by server.

I want to create a new project compatible with Java EE 6 (without application.xml, without web.xml, using annotation). However I have to use ejb 2.x project as a jar. My question is that How I can accomplish this task.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Please forget that EJB 2.x has ever existed and use EJB 3.x. 2.x was a real pain and it's not worth it, since a new, much simplified, specification (3.x) has been published for almost 8 years now.

Comment: Thank you Stefano. ejb 2.x project not belong to me but I have to use it. migration is being planned by the project owner but I have time problem.

Comment: Is this specifically a question about RAD (if yes, please add the `rad` tag to the front of the list), or is this a question about Java EE 6 in general?  If the latter, you add an EJB 2.x module the same as any other module: just include it in the EAR.  Since it's an EJB 2.x module, it must have an `ejb-jar.xml`, so if you don't have an `application.xml`, it will discovered automatically.

Comment: Question is about general. Can I use an EJB project as a utility JAR not as a project? XYZEJB.jar is already conform to the specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EJB 2.1 and 3.x in parallel, we also have that in an application which is quite some years old and still not completely migrated.

For the old parts, you still need the same setup with all the deployment descriptors, as @bkail pointed out.

But if possible, I would strongly recommend not to mix up things if you have the chance to create a modern JavaEE 6 based application. Better try to interface with the old parts which are still needed and keep it as a separate application and use old EJBs or introduce a temporary interface between old and new application until it is migrated.

Comment: If An ejb2.x bean(BeanA) uses another ejb(BeanB), BeanA must link to BeanB  in ejb-jar.xml. But in Ejb 3.1 this task is done by @EJB annotation. I think Lookup method must use in case of accessing Bean2.x from Bean3.1. I don't use directly EJB 2.x bean in my new EJB 3.1 project. I am using a wrapper class which wraps ejb bean. But at this time lookup is failed from 3.1 to 2.x ejb. How to fix lookup problem?

Comment: You can directly inject 2.x beans into a 3.1 bean by using the (container specific) JNDI name under which it is registered. See example [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/6604754). That's what I meant with trying to interface it, instead putting both into one application.

Comment: I realized that When server is restarted Websphere App. Server(WAS) logs as following  ...The binding location is: ejblocal:ejb/tr/gov/system/ejb/SystemUtilitiesManagerLocalHome
....The binding location is: java:global/AsyncMessagingEAR/SystemEJB/SystemUtilitiesManager!tr.gov.system.ejb.SystemUtilitiesManagerLocalHome
I use first one to lookup. Is this approach is global or specific to WAS.